# Properties of the symmetric square of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, number-theory, algebraic-curves

Under what conditions on a curve $C$, defined over a ring $R$, is its symmetric square, $C^{(2)}$ smooth/proper? Is it enough for $C$ itself to be smooth/proper over $\text{Spec}R$?

How does one see this? Is there any reference to these statements?

Comment: Put $S:=\operatorname{Spec}R $. $C^{(2)}$ is the quotient of $C\times _{S}C$ by the involution $\sigma $ which exchanges the factors. So it is proper if $p:C\rightarrow S$ is proper, and smooth if $p$ is smooth, because the fixed locus of $\sigma $ has codimension 1.

Comment: Could you explain please why the square is proper, and under which conditions the quotient is proper?

Comment: This is very basic. A pull back of a proper map is proper. If $g\circ f$ is proper and $f$ surjective, $g$ is proper.